# Add products to customer cart from admin panel

Tags: magento

Is there a way to add products to customers cart from admin panel by selecting a customer. Instead of creating order for customer just create a cart from admin and ask customer to login and proceed for payment.

Answer (score 1):

To access customer's quote from the admin,You can do,

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($yourId); 

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, In magento there is an option in admin to create order where we can select customer and add products and create order from admin. I dont want to create order. Instead would like to just select the customer and add some products to the cart. Then customer will login and those products will be there in his cart.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I know to do this is:
Orders -> Create New Order -> Select customer and store if applicable.
Add products to the order, then for each item, select “Move to Shopping Cart” and click Update Items and Qty’s button.

But if there’s a better way to do this, I’d also like to know.